# Converting mongodb aggregrate into Spring Boot equivalent

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have a working aggregrate :

```
db.getCollection("policies").aggregate([

                      { $match: { "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.RatingStateProvCd.Value": "IL" , "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.CompanyProductCd.Value" :  "027" , 
                                         "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.InitialDataOrderLineCd.Value"  :   "010" } },

                 { $project:{            "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd": 1        }    }                  ,
                   { $unwind: { path: "$policyData.QuoteOrPolicy", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } ,
                 { $unwind: { path: "$policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } ,
                 { $unwind: { path: "$policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } ,
                   { $unwind: { path: "$policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } ,
                    { $group: { _id: "$policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd.Value", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
                    {$group:{"_id":null,"coverage_counts":{$push:{"coverage_value":"$_id",
                                               "count":"$count"}}}},
                    {$project:{"_id":0,"coverage_counts":1}}

             ])
```

that works as expected.
I'm having no joy getting the equivalent working in Spring Boot using its mongodb support aggregates.

Can anyone "translate" it .
Thanks for all info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to familiarize yourself with the [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html) library to better understand how to use mongodb's aggregate inside of spring.

Here is an example of how you would use it using your query:

```
mongoOperation.aggregate( Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match( Criteria.where( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.RatingStateProvCd.Value" ).is( "IL" )
                .and( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.CompanyProductCd.Value" ).is( "027" )
                .and( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.Policy.InitialDataOrderLineCd.Value" ).is( "010" ) ),
                Aggregation.project().and( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy" ).as( "QuoteOrPolicy" ),
                Aggregation.unwind( "QuoteOrPolicy", true ),
                Aggregation.unwind( "QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness", true ),
                Aggregation.unwind( "QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh", true ),
                Aggregation.unwind( "QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage", true ),
                Aggregation.group( "QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd.Value" ).count().as( "count" ),
                Aggregation.group().push( new Document( "coverage_value", "$_id" ).append( "count", "$count" ) ).as( "coverage_counts" ),
                Aggregation.project( "coverage_counts" )
             ), "NameOfYourCollection", Document.class );
```

The Document.class at the end can be changed out for a class if it has the matching fields of your query's output.

Comment: This worked a treat and thank you very much.One small change was replacing Document with BasicDBObject. I'm curious , how u knew to Aggregation.project().and( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy" ).as( "QuoteOrPolicy" ) ?I tried Aggregation.project("policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd") which I felt should work as it same as original but didn't. The { $project:{            "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd": 1        }    }  gets the smallest piece of dataI needed but does not seem to "translate" as is to Spring Boot.

Comment: Document and BasicDBObject are kind of interchangeable, it is all dependent on which version of spring-boot you use, I currently use 2.2 which strongly recommends replacing BasicDBObject with Document. As for the project, when dealing with objects being the values in the field you want to stay as near the top as possible until you have the data you want then drill into. Also aggregation in spring is really literal so if you drill down like you did in your original query you would only get a small fraction of the data you wanted. And remember to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will certainly accept the answer for sure. Still a bit concerned as the original only got the min data and it worked (outside of SpringBoot :)) and should reduce the memory footprint on Mongo whereas the projection at the highest level will return more data and those structures are quite meaty for me. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: A further update:If I change { $project:{            "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd": 1        }    }                    to { $project:{            "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.": 1        }    } in my original MongoDb query it makes the query execute 7 times slower and that is also reflected in the Spring Boot version :(  This is a problem as query has a lot of data to process and projecting at the higher level results in a large structure being returned for each row to be processed.Any ideas?Would using "@Aggregrate" perform better? @josh-balcitis

Comment: Not sure. Indexes on the collection can help the speed of the query, but without knowing the data structure itself I can't really say how best to improve the performance. Sorry!

Comment: @johnharkin Have you tried using your original project, policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd, but skip the 4 unwinds. Unwinds are usually where all the slow down come from because they grow the result set the next operation has to deal with. I haven't tried this myself, you might have to experiment by adding/removing operations to best refine your query for spring-boot.

Comment: @johnharkin So the project and first group would look like this: Aggregation.project().and( "policyData.QuoteOrPolicy.PersAutoLineBusiness.PersAutoVeh.Coverage.CoverageCd" ).as( "CoverageCd" ), Aggregation.group( "CoverageCd.Value" ).count().as( "count" )

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and your time. I've implemented an alternative using the "@Aggregation" as per https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/08/what-s-new-in-spring-data-moore and it works a treat based on my original aggregation with no perf issues.

Comment: @johnharkin No problem, and I would curious to see which implementation performs better overall. I can definitely see the appeal of that approach, given you can just use json queries and get access to all of mongo functionality, like the advanced lookup for example ( damn you Aggregation library, develop new versions faster! ) . Though I wonder how it would deal with a multiple DB setup like the one I have.